# OpenCV Face Detection - vector issue

Tags: iphone, c++, opencv

I'm using the following code to perform face detection using OpenCV on the iPhone.

```
std::vector<Rect> faces;

face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, cv::Size(15, 15) );
```

However, when I try to build the app, an error is thrown at the `detectMultiScale` function call.  "No matching member function call to 'detectMultiScale'".

The following further explanation is given:

[image: Error Message]

The errors read: `Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::vector<Rect>'  to 'vector<Rect> &' for 2nd argument.`

What is going on here?  Evidently the compiler takes issue with the second argument.  Am I using a different type of vector?

Thanks, James

XCode 4.2.1
SDK 5.0
OpenCV 2.

Comment: I don't know are you? If you remove the `std::` namespace explicit scope does it compile? If so then look for the definition of `vector` in OpenCV as they may have defined their own. There is a `cv::Vector` which may be the type you should be using ... I'm not familiar with this library.

Comment: Pretty sure I'm supposed to be using `std::`.  Tried `cv::` with no effect.

Comment: Perhaps try a `using std::vector;` directive then declaring it as  `vector<Rect> faces;` it seems to think a conversion is needed due to the scope qualifier causing the overload not to match.

Comment: no effect. very strange.

Comment: Does changing the definition of the second parameter to `std::vector<RECT> &objects` help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add

```
using namespace cv;
```

at the beginning.